# Missing return statement when trying to return a boolean value

Tags: java, return, statements

I keep getting an error in java and I don't know why "missing return statement". What I'm trying to do is create a method with two parameters (String and char) check if the char appears in the string and return a boolean value based on the comparison. Here's what I have so far:

```
  public static boolean compare(String h, char x){

int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < h.length(); i++){
  counter++;
  if(h.charAt(i) == 'o'){
    return true;
  }
  else
    return false;
}

  }
```

Again, the error in the console is "missing return statement".
Please be aware that I'm not an expert in Java and probably I have more errors in my code, my apologize in advance for that.

edit: Don't look at the indentation, I just copy and paste the code here.
edit 2: "h" is "Hello world" in my code.

Comment: Add curly braces for else code and check.

Comment: Hint: what if h is empty

Comment: *Don't look at the indentation* When your code is indented like that, I and others cannot read it.  If you were to intend it properly, your issue would become clear.

Comment: @JoeC the code in the editor is correct, I don't know why is indented like that here, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should assign the boolean result to a variable instead of returning it in the loop. Add the return statement after the for loop, this should fix your issue. HTH

```
 public static boolean compare(String h, char x){

       int counter = 0;
       boolean flag = false;

       for(int i = 0; i < h.length(); i++){
         counter++;
         if(h.charAt(i) == 'o'){
             flag = true;
         }
         else
             flag = false;
       }
        return flag;
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the logic should contain the given `char` value `o` in `String` parameter `h`, it will be `true` only if the last character of the `String` is `o` else it returns `false`. You can use an `if-else` instead of the above logic (or) you can break the `for-loop` once you find the first occurrence of the `char` If my assumption is correct

Answer (score 0):

That's because of your `if` and `else` conditions are in a for loop.
The for loop itself is a conditional loop.

There can be a scenario if your `if` or `else` stays unreached.
You need to return a boolean outside of the for loop here.

**Example scenario:**
**'h' is an empty String.**

**EDIT:** And as per your statement **"h" is "Hello world" in my code**, at the time of compilation, the complier isn't looking at the value that is being passed to 'h'.
Your **compare** method is an individual identity and it is not at all limited to a single use only.

Answer (score 0):

because of your for loop `i < h.length()` if `h.length()` is `0` then code inside for loop is unreachable so it show error for missing return statement.